# How to remove item from listbox and have changes reflected in entity

Tags: c#, data-binding, listbox, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to bind an entity to a listbox, and when I remove something from the entity, I want it to be reflected in the listbox.

Here is a code snippet:

```
SportsClubEntities spe = new SportsClubEntities

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();


var stm = 
    from xyz in spe.SomeEntity where xyz.prop == 66
    select new { Name = xyz.name, rec = xyz }

bs.DataSource = stm.ToList();

ListBox.DataSource = bs;
ListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
ListBox.ValueMember = "rec";
```

I have a button, which when I click, I want it to remove the selected item in the listbox, but more than that, I want it to remove the item from the underlying entity.  ie: when xyz is selected and removed from the listbox, I want xyz removed from spe.

If I do a `bs.Remove(item)` that removes the item from the listbox (when I then call `bs.ResetBindings()`, but it doesn't update the entity (`spe.SomeEntity`).  Initially, I thought it would, but then I realised that the LINQ is a query, returning some results.

When I click the remove button, I can do `spe.SomeEntity.Remove(item)`, but then the listbox doesn't get updated.

Is there a way I can perform the remove on just one of the them, and have both updated?

Am I doing this completely wrong?  Is there some sort of 'standard' way to do this sort of thing?

I can't bind `spe.SomeEntity.ToList()` to the listbox directly, because I need a subset of the records in the entity.

Appreciate any help, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list1 = new List<Person>();

        using (SportsClubEntities spe = new SportsClubEntities())
        {
            list1 = (from p in spe.People
                      select p).ToList();
        }

        bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = list1;

        listBox1.DataSource = bs;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person p1 = (Person)listBox1.SelectedItem;
        list1.Remove((Person)listBox1.SelectedItem);
        bs.ResetBindings(false);

        using (SportsClubEntities spe = new SportsClubEntities())
        {
            Person p2 = (from p in spe.People
                     where p.BusinessEntityID == p1.BusinessEntityID
                     select p).FirstOrDefault();

            spe.People.Remove(p2);
            spe.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Removing a guy named "Jossef":

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, I really appreciate it.  I was (ideally) looking for a solution that would allow me to remove an item once without having to really remove it from the listbox and then the entity separately.

I was also looking for some general guidance on the "best way" or "most correct" way of implementing this.

Comment: Why do you think this is not the "most correct" way of doing it?

Comment: Show me the line of code where something is being removed from the list box.

Comment: Can you explain the different roles played by `list1`, `listbox1` and `spe` in the code above?

Comment: If you don't understand that, then you have to do some studying on your own before concluding it is not the "most correct" way of doing it.

Comment: Did you try this code on your own? Did it worked as intended?

Comment: Have you ever heard of MVVM? Can you identify who's the Model and who's the View in this code?

Comment: What about the "data access layer". Who plays DAL in this code?

Comment: Have you heard of "separation of concerns"?

Comment: Do you even have any specific questions about the code that i could answer?

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A web site, not a tutoring service.

Comment: Hi jstreet. Sorry if I caused any offence.  When I was talking about the "most correct way", I mean that I was _looking to find_ the most correct way, not that your way wasn't the most correct way.

The line where something is being removed from the list box is:
`list1.Remove((Person)listBox1.SelectedItem);`
as it is the datasource and the resetbindings would cause a refresh.

Yes, I can explain the roles played by `list1`, `listbox1` and `spe`.

Comment: As I tried to explain above, I wasn't saying your way isn't the most correct, just that part of the reason for my post was that I was looking for the most correct way.

Comment: Yes, the code you provided did work as intended, I was just wondering if via binding there was a way to update the listbox and underlying entity at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I've heard of MVVM, not really sure about how to implement it though.

Comment: No, that line is removing an item from `list1`, not from `listbox1`, look again.

Comment: Yes, I've heard of 'separation of concerns' and I get the idea.

Comment: You can think it is not correct, but you have to explain why...:O)

Comment: I don't have any specific questions about the code you provided - it works fine.

My only other question would be is there a technique that will allow a single remove that will act on the entitiy and be reflected in the listbox at the same time?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the purpose of StackOverflow.  No need to be nasty.

Comment: did you look again at the line where you think an item is being removed from `listbox1`, but it is not?

Comment: I know that the line I specified is removing an item from `list1`, but as `list1` is the datasource of the listbox, when the ResetBindings() is called, that will refresh the `listbox1`.  Or at least that's my understanding.

Comment: To try and clarify further, I'm not saying what you posted is "not correct", I was just wondering what the _most_ correct way of doing this is?  Perhaps your way is the most correct - I don't know - that's why I was asking!

Comment: exactly, nothing is EVER removed from the listbox, only from list1, you need to understand that. So, whenever list1 is updated, listbox is update, would you agree with that?

Comment: Gotta go, but I'll be back.  Thank you again for helping by providing a solution.

Comment: Sure, please come back whenever you find the "most correct" way of doing it and educate myself about it. Thank you.